# "Allow USB debugging?" keeps popping up

Tags: android, adb, android-wifi, usb-debugging, android-vpn-service

I'm going nuts here. I am trying to debug my app on a Samsung Galaxy Tab S5e.

My application runs a [VPNService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService) and I am reasonably sure this is the root cause of the following issue:

When debugging via USB, everything works fine. However, when I debug over WIFI, it keeps prompting me to "Allow USB debugging", saying something about the computers RSA key fingerprint and whether I want to "always allow from this computer", which I obviously select and then click "allow".

If I try debug my app again, it will again prompt me...

I've tried:

- restarting the device.
- killing adb and starting it again
- restarting my machine (Macbook Pro)
- revoking all USB debugging authorisations
- deleting the `adbkey.pub` and `adbkey` files
- FACTORY RESET OF DEVICE

Nothing works.

Does anyone know how I can solve this? I have to go via wireless because I need to measure energy consumption... which I cannot do if the device is being charged.

Comment: You might be able to disable charging during USB debugging. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731921/how-to-disable-battery-charging-during-adb-connection/45267088#45267088

Comment: You are debugging over WIFI. Are you in the same network as your home router? Your VPN can change your network. Also, it might be related to which IDI plugin you use for wifi debug.

Comment: @FatihŞennik Yeh, debugging over WIFI and on home network - both laptop and tablet on same network.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. I haven't found the root cause of this issue. But the workaround that worked for me is:

**Connect your device ( mobile phone ) and your computer to the same WiFi network**